# Using wildcards in function in rules

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake

I want to do a specific trimming for each sample I have in my pipeline.

I have a list of samples in my config below:

```
#######################
#      Config data    # 
#######################

samples:
  3373-1_CCGCGGTT-CTAGCGCT-AHV5HLDSXY_L004:
  3373-2_TTATAACC-TCGATATC-AHV5HLDSXY_L004:
  3373-3_GGACTTGG-CGTCTGCG-AHV5HLDSXY_L004:
  3373-4_AAGTCCAA-TACTCATA-AHV5HLDSXY_L004: 
  ....
```

And another list in my config with the samples and primers as a dictionary for trim5 and trim3.

```
trim5:
  3373-1_CCGCGGTT-CTAGCGCT-AHV5HLDSXY_L004: GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACCCGCGGTTATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG 
  3373-2_TTATAACC-TCGATATC-AHV5HLDSXY_L004: GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACTTATAACCATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG
  3373-3_GGACTTGG-CGTCTGCG-AHV5HLDSXY_L004: GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACGGACTTGGATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG
  3373-4_AAGTCCAA-TACTCATA-AHV5HLDSXY_L004: GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACAAGTCCAAATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG
 .....
```

So I made a function that allows to select the primer linked to this sample.

```
# get_index_trim5/3 allow to verify that we use the correct adaptater depending of the correct sequence
def get_index_trim5():
      for trim3 in config['trim5']:
             if {wildcards.sample} == trim5:
                print (config['trim5'])
                print (config['trim5'][trim5])
                    return ( config['trim5'][trim5] )
             else: 
                    continue 
         
            

# get_index_trim5/3 allow to verify that we use the correct adaptater depending of the correct sequence
def get_index_trim3():
      for trim3 in config['trim3']:      
            if {wildcards.sample} == trim3:
                print (config['trim3'])
                print (config['trim3'][trim3])
                    return ( config['trim3'][trim3] )
             else: 
                    continue
            

  

rule cutadapt_remove_adaptater_trimm:
    priority: 0
    input:
        reads=["../resources/sequences/{sample}_R1.fastq.gz", "../resources/sequences/{sample}_R2.fastq.gz"]
    output:
        fastq1= "../results/trimmed/{sample}_R1_trimmed.fastq.gz",
        fastq2= "../results/trimmed/{sample}_R2_trimmed.fastq.gz",
        qc= "../results/trimmed/{sample}_qc.txt"
    params:
        adapters="-g %s -a %s -a %s -a %s  -G %s -A %s -A %s -A %s -A %s  "%(get_index_trim5(), config['adaptaters']['adap_R1'], config['adaptaters']['PolyAG'],get_index_trim3(), get_index_trim5(), config['adaptaters']['adap_R2'], get_index_trim3(), config['adaptaters']['PolyG']), 
        extra="--minimum-length 100 -q 20"
    log:
        "../results/logs/trimmed/{sample}_trimmed.log"
    benchmark : 
        "../results/benchmarks/trimmed/{sample}_trimmed_benchmark.txt"
    message:
        """
        --- Trimming on {wildcards.sample} {params.adapters} in process ---
        """
    threads: 4
    resources:
        mem_mb=25000
    shell:
      "cutadapt {params.adapters} {params.extra} -o {output.fastq1} -p {output.fastq2} -j {threads} {input.reads} > {output.qc} 2> {log}"
```

The problem is I need to check in my function that the wildcards correspond to the primer but I can't pass the wildcards.sample as an argument to my function.
I have some difficulties to use wildcards

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day,
aka

**##########################################################**

```
            EDIT Solution
```

**###########################################################**

Hello,

Finally I found the solution.
The first problem was that I used the function `get_index_trim5()` but we don't need `()`.

Then the second problem was that I tried to call a function with the %s and it returned an object of the function not the key I want.

So, it's not perfect but it solves my problem, I decided to split my adapter variable into different variables in my `params` part: R1 and R2 for my classic adapters without the functions `get_index_trim5` and `get_index_trim3` and two other variables with my functions directly.

Like that I called my params. in my bash command for cutadapt.

```
def get_index_trim5(wildcards):
    trim5 =wildcards.sample
    return config['trim5'][trim5]
 

def get_index_trim3(wildcards):
    trim3 =wildcards.sample
    return config['trim3'][trim3]


rule cutadapt_remove_adaptater_trimm:
    priority: 0
    input:
        reads=["../resources/sequences/{sample}_R1.fastq.gz", "../resources/sequences/{sample}_R2.fastq.gz"]
    output:
        fastq1= "../results/trimmed/{sample}_R1_trimmed.fastq.gz",
        fastq2= "../results/trimmed/{sample}_R2_trimmed.fastq.gz",
        qc= "../results/trimmed/{sample}_qc.txt"
    params:
        adapters_r1=" -a %s -a %s %s"%(config['adaptaters']['adap_R1'], config['adaptaters']['PolyAG']),
        adapters_r2= "-A %s -A %s "%(config['adaptaters']['adap_R2'], config['adaptaters']['PolyG']),
        extra="--minimum-length 100 -q 20",
        trim5=get_index_trim5,
        trim3=get_index_trim3
    log:
        "../results/logs/trimmed/{sample}_trimmed.log"
    benchmark : 
        "../results/benchmarks/trimmed/{sample}_trimmed_benchmark.txt"
    message:
        """
        --- Trimming on {wildcards.sample} {params.adapters_r1}
        
        {params.adapters_r2}  in process ---

        {params.trim5} {params.trim3}]
        """
    threads: 4
    resources:
        mem_mb=25000
    shell:
      "cutadapt -g {params.trim5} {params.adapters_r1} -a {params.trim3} -G {params.trim5} {params.adapters_r2} -A {params.trim3} {params.extra} -o {output.fastq1} -p {output.fastq2} -j {threads} {input.reads} > {output.qc} 2> {log}"
```

Aka

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't pass the wildcards.sample as an argument to my function.

You can work around it by combining your custom function with a `lambda` expression:

```
def get_index_trim3(sample, config):
    for trim3 in config['trim3']:      
        if sample == trim3:
             print (config['trim3'])
             print (config['trim3'][trim3])
                 return ( config['trim3'][trim3] )
         else: 
             continue

rule cutadapt:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: get_index_trim3(wildcards.sample, config)
    ...
```

By the way, I don't know your specific case but usually you don't need to specify the full adapter sequence. Use the first common bases as a catch-all for all of them, like:

```
cutadapt -a GATCGGAAGAGCAC ...
```

Maybe try and see if it works...